# Hadoop ls command not working

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am able to create directories in HDFS but when I submit 'ls' command it is giving the error mentioned below. I got the same error when I gave bin/hadoop dfs –ls /. What am I missing?

```
hduser@Server-8-22:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop fs -mkdir skalburginput
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

hduser@Server-8-22:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop fs -mkdir skalburgoutput
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

hduser@Server-8-22:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop fs –ls
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

ls: Unknown command
Usage: java FsShell
       [-ls <path>]
       [-lsr <path>]
       [-du <path>]
       [-dus <path>]
       [-count[-q] <path>]
       [-mv <src> <dst>]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While making directory Mention the full path for the directory, starting from the root.
i.e:
/your/location/skalburginput

For the ls command, Try:

$hdfs dfs -ls /